# I am not getting distinct result with related field

Tags: django

models.py

```
class PlayLists(models.Model):
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class PlayListVideos(models.Model):
    coach      = models.ForeignKey(coachRegister, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='playlist_videos',null=True,blank=True)
    video      = models.ForeignKey(VideosModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='playlists_videos',null=True,blank=True)
    playlist   = models.ForeignKey(PlayLists, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='playlists_videos',null=True,blank=True)
```

views.py

```
    from .models import PlayListVideos
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    from django.db.models import count

    def playlists(request):
        res = list(PlayListVideos.objects.values('playlist__name','video__url','video__title').annotate(videos=Count('playlist__name')))
        return JsonResponse(res, safe=False)
```

getting result:

```
    [
      {
        "video__url": "DX-FIfLb19A",
        "videos": 1,
        "playlist__name": "game of thrones",
        "video__title": "70th Emmy Awards: Peter Dinklage Wins For Outstanding Supporting Actor In A Drama Series"
      },
      {
        "video__url": "rlesc2MYVoA",
        "videos": 1,
        "playlist__name": "game of thrones",
        "video__title": "Game of Thrones 7x05 - Jon Snow meets Drogon - Daenerys reunites with Jorah"
      },
      {
        "video__url": "mk1DXwb-XbM",
        "videos": 1,
        "playlist__name": "mylist",
        "video__title": "Game of Thrones 7x03 - Jon Snow meets Daenerys Targaryen"
      }
    ]
```

expecting result:

```
    [
      {
        "video__url":[
            "rlesc2MYVoA",
            "DX-FIfLb19A"
        ],
        "videos": 2,
        "playlist__name": "game of thrones",
        "video__title":[
            "70th Emmy Awards: Peter Dinklage Wins For Outstanding Supporting Actor In A Drama Series",
            "Game of Thrones 7x05 - Jon Snow meets Drogon - Daenerys reunites with Jorah"
        ]
      },
      {
        "video__url":[
            "mk1DXwb-XbM"
        ],
        "videos": 1,
        "playlist__name": "mylist",
        "video__title":[
            "Game of Thrones 7x03 - Jon Snow meets Daenerys Targaryen"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Here i am expecting distinct result as per playlist__name
and i have used aggregate query still i am not getting distinct value as per playlist__name

The distinct work for single model while fetching data. but it is not 
working with related fields

Please have a look

Comment: try this **annotate(videos=Count('playlists_videos__name')))**

Answer (score -3):

this is exception use try except envent handling or error handling your code

Comment: Again, what does this have to do with the question?